# android media player shows audio but no video

Tags: android, streaming, media-player

I am using media player to stream a video. It only plays the audio but not the video. Could anyone help? My code is below.

```
public class VideoViewApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
    }
}


public class VideoViewDemo extends Activity implements 

    OnErrorListener,OnBufferingUpdateListener, OnCompletionListener,
    MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback  {

    private static final String TAG = "VideoViewDemo";

    private MediaPlayer mp;
    private EditText mPath;  
    private SurfaceHolder holder;

    private ImageButton mPlay;
        private ImageButton mPause;
    private ImageButton mReset;
    private ImageButton mStop;
    private String current;
    private SurfaceView mPreview;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);

        mPath = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.path);
        mPath.setText("rtsp://video2.americafree.tv/AFTVHorrorH26496.sdp");

        mPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play);
        mPause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pause);
        mReset = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.reset);
        mStop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.stop);


        mPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                playVideo();
            }
        });
        mPause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mp != null) {
                    mp.pause();
                }
            }
        });
        mReset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mp != null) {
                    mp.seekTo(0);
                }
            }
        });
        mStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mp != null) {
                    current = null;
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.release();
                }
            }
        });

        // getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
        holder = mPreview.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        holder.setFixedSize(100, 100);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                playVideo();
            }
        });
    }

    private void playVideo() {
        try {
            final String path = mPath.getText().toString();
            Log.v(TAG, "path: " + path);

            if (path.equals(current) && mp != null) {
                mp.start();
                return;
            }
            current = path;

            mp = new MediaPlayer();
            mp.setOnErrorListener(this);
            mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mp.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);

            mp.setDisplay(mPreview.getHolder());
            mp.setDataSource(path);
            mp.prepare();

            Log.v(TAG, "Duration: ===>" + mp.getDuration());
            mp.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error: "+ e.getMessage(), e);
            if (mp != null) {
                mp.stop();
                mp.release();
            }
        }
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceChanged called");
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceCreated called");
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed called");
    }

    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared called");
    }

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCompletion called");
    }

    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int percent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBufferingUpdate called --->   percent:" + percent);
    }

    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int what, int extra) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onError---> what:"+what+"   extra:"+extra);
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
        return true;
    }


}



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <EditText android:id="@+id/path"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/surface"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </SurfaceView>

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            >
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/play"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:src="@drawable/play"/>
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/pause"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:src="@drawable/pause"/>
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/reset"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:src="@drawable/reset"/>
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/stop"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:src="@drawable/stop"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you are trying to run this on the emulator, this is normal behavior. The emulator cannot render video on most development machines. For testing video apps, you really need a device.

Comment: I am running it on a samsung galaxy tab. I suspect that is related to the layout xml and the holder size.

Comment: Sometimes this happens if the device can't quite handle that video's encoding details.  As a test, take a short piece of the subject video, load it onto the device, and play it with the stock player.

Answer (score 11):

I had this problem and solved it by setting the type using this depreciated method.

```
holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
```

Worth a try, and if it works you could investigate why the type isn't automatically set as it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it was due to the surface not being ready to play back video.

You should try and call playVideo() from the surfaceCreated() handler.

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                playVideo();
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and solved it by adding in my release function visible=gone to surfaceview:

```
  public void release() {
    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
    setVisibility(View.GONE);
      mMediaPlayer.reset();
      mMediaPlayer.release();
      mMediaPlayer = null;
      mCurrentState = STATE_IDLE;}
  }
```

and set visible=visible in onprepared function:

```
   videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                audio=false; video=false; int ty=mp.getTrackInfo().length;
                for (int i=0; i<ty;i++)
                {
                    if (mp.getAudioTrack()>-1) {audio=true;}
                    if (mp.getVideoTrack()>-1) {video=true;}
                }

                if (((audio==false)&&(skip==true))||((video==false)&&(skip2==true))||((video==true)&&(skip4==true))) 
                {   notifybar("...");
                    nexttr();} else {
                if (vis==true) {
                if (video==false) {
                    if (mVisualizerView.getVisibility()!=View.VISIBLE) {mVisualizerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
                        mVisualizerView.link(videoView.getAudioSessionId());
                        vis2=true;
                        } else if (vis2==true){
                       mVisualizerView.release();
                       mVisualizerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                      vis2=false;
                        }}
                //this
                if (video==true) {
                if (videoView.getVisibility()!=View.VISIBLE) {videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
                } else {if (videoView.getVisibility()!=View.INVISIBLE) {videoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);}
                }
```